# Apache mod_rewrite sets request method to "GET" if directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm currently developing an API using a self-written router. It uses an `.htaccess` file to redirect all incoming requests to the `index.php` file.

I have found the following problem: If there is an incoming request e.g.: `OPTIONS https://<domain>/auth` and the directory `auth/` exists on the root-level, the request method is switched to `GET`.

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try disabling MultiViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because mod_dir issues a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash to directories (in order to "fix" the URL). A consequence of the 301 redirect is that the *user-agent* (browser) changes the subsequent request method to `GET`.

If you specifically want to allow these types of requests then you'll need to prevent mod_dir from appending the slash with `DirectorySlash Off`. However, you will also need to ensure that mod_autoindex (auto generated directory listings) are disabled (to prevent accidental disclosure of information) and you could potentially encounter issues if you need to access directories directly elsewhere.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir from appending the slash to directories
DirectorySlash Off
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

---

*Aside:*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

These `RewriteCond` directives are superfluous. You are rewriting literally *everything* to `index.php`. It would be more efficient to write this as:

```
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```